# SimpleCursorAdapter(ListView заполняется данными после прокрутки скрола)

Tags: android

Помогите решить задачу.
У меня ListView начинает заполняться данными, только после первой прокрутки списка. Т.е в начальный момент список пустой.

```
DB db = new DB(getActivity().getBaseContext());
db.open();

c = db.getData();
    if(c!=null){
String[] from = new String[] { DB.COLUMN_NAME};
            int[] to = new int[] {R.id.tvName};
MyDataAdapter adapter = new MyDataAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_list_view, c, from, to);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

          }else{
              c.close();
          }
```

Вот мой адаптер:

```
public class MyDataAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
private Cursor cursor;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ViewHolder holder;
private String rowID;
// itemChecked will store the position of the checked items.

public MyDataAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
        int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.cursor = c;
    this.context = context;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {
        itemChecked.add(i, false); // initializes all items value with false
    }
}

class ViewHolder {

    public CheckBox cBox;
}

public View getView(final int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inView == null) {
       inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.cBox = (CheckBox) inView.findViewById(R.id.chbox1); // your

        inView.setTag(holder);
    }else {

         holder = (ViewHolder) inView.getTag();
         bindView(inView, context, cursor);

    }

    // CheckBox
    holder.cBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chbox1);

            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                itemChecked.set(pos, true);
                Toast.makeText(context, "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // do some operations here
            } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                itemChecked.set(pos, false);
                // do some operations here
                Toast.makeText(context, "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    holder.cBox.setChecked(itemChecked.get(pos)); // this will Check or Uncheck the

    return inView;
}

}
```

Comment: Покажите код, как вы грузите этот адаптер

Comment: а вопрос то какой?

Comment: Как сделать так что бы список заполнялся данными, а не после прокрутки скролла.
Сдается мне что засада где-то здесь:
if (inView == null) {

}else{

}